# Using wso2 esb multipart /form data

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In wso2 ESB when multipart/formdata request comes for ESB API I want to first store the request and then afterwards I want to use that property.

Below is the API code.

```
<api context="/multi" name="multi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
            <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
            <respond/>
</inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>

Request:
key : file  value:image
key : json  value:{"a":"b"}
```

Response i'm getting is correct:

```
--MIMEBoundary_9e01467992befaaccfd1aa25f3e48a26d18d37e547e64c30
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.png"
Content-Type: image/png; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
--MIMEBoundary_9e01467992befaaccfd1aa25f3e48a26d18d37e547e64c30
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
sdkjahkshdkkhk..............(Image)
{ "a":"b"}
--MIMEBoundary_9e01467992befaaccfd1aa25f3e48a26d18d37e547e64c30--
```

But as I wanted to process the property mediator having json payload of multipart request to use afterwards and convert to multipart format, so if I use below API code I' getting wrong response.

```
<api context="/multi" name="multi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <resource methods="POST">
            <inSequence>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
 <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="inputPayLoad" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var rp = mc.getProperty("inputPayLoad");
        mc.setPayloadJSON(rp);]]></script>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
                <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="multipart/form-data"/>
                <respond/>
    </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
            <faultSequence/>
        </resource>
    </api>
```

But response I'm getting is

```
--MIMEBoundary_9e01467992befaacae1a7a25f3e48a26818d37e547e64c30
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mediate"
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<mediate><file>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAIAAAAiOj........./file><json>{ "a":"b"}</json></mediate>
--MIMEBoundary_9e01467992befaacae1a7a25f3e48a26818d37e547e64c30--
```

There is a difference between two response, but both the request before converting to multipart/formdata format(property mediator) are same like

```
{
"mediate":{
"file":"dksad..",
"json":"{"a":"b"}"
}
}
```

But I am not understanding why ESB is giving different response for same request(json) before converting to multipart.

Answer (score 0):

The Response which you are getting is base64 Encoded, can you decode it by using base64 decoder and see the response